# Jquery validate plugin for live validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm working on jquery validate plugin for form live validation

```
{
    //....
    rules: {
        fullname: {
            required: true,
            lettersonly: true
        },
        age:{ 
            required: true,
            number: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        fullname: {
            required: "Please enter your fullname",
            minlength: "fullname must be at least 4 characters long"
        },
        age:{
            required: "Please enter your age",
            number : "Your input must be number"
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Using this code I'm getting validation on age field but not working or getting any message for fullname field.What I'm doing wrong.

Comment: please check your html name attribute.

Comment: fullname is my name attribute,it is not working

Comment: but for age it is working

Comment: can you add link.

Comment: right now working on local server

Comment: <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control one_third shadow" placeholder="Age">
                                <input name="fullname" id="fullname" type="text" class="form-control one_third shadow" placeholder="Full Name">

Comment: name="fullname123"   should be name="fullname"

Comment: form field code is this

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Comment: using this library link

Comment: I have updated also

Comment: name="fullname"

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"/>

Comment: use this library

Comment: still not working

Comment: Do you link to the additional methods?

Comment: no,I used just above code

Comment: Incomplete example that fails to demonstrate any part of this problem and four of you upvoted it??  **Show more completed code that includes the full `.validate()` method and the relevant HTML markup.**

Comment: The code as you posted it, including code you posted in comments, is working perfectly fine.  Include the `additional-methods.js` file for `lettersonly` method.  **DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/bs0q6c3r/**

Comment: Sparkly it is working fine after adding additional-method.js file.
I have not include this file before.